# how display image view with out losing image clarity

Tags: iphone

i am have a image of size 200X200,i need to place it in 15X15 size imageview.

just like thumbnail,but i loos clarity of image.

but i need to display image with clarity,is there any way to display image view image without loss of clarity.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are maintaining the aspect ratio, it should not cause much problem. But from 200x200 to 15x15 is like asking too much to fit in a too small space, you will definitely lose details, why don't you create an image of 15x15 straight way.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can't put 200 pixels into 15 pixels and keep the same quality.